# Difference between stem cell "expansion", "repopulation", and "self-renewal"?

Tags: terminology, stem-cells

From this paper (link:https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4130805/), I read "Thus G-CSF results in the expansion of phenotypic HSCs in the bone marrow with reduced repopulating activity and self-renewal capacity."

If expansion meant population-expansion, then would that not mean the same thing as repopulation? Likewise, self-renewal occurs through asymmetric cell-division in which a parent cell divides into two daughter cells; or it can occur through symmetric cell-division in which a parent cell divides into a progenitor cell and a daughter cell. In essence, both types of cell-division maintain or increases the population of stem cells; hence, "self-renew" or "expand". Clearly, I am missing something here with the terminologies. Please help! Lastly, I thought phenotype is a noun, then what does phenotypic even mean?

Comment: will you be still interested in a few days time?

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler: Yes! Please help! I need this.

Comment: I will read paper this weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of reading the paper (from 2014), if you can I recommend instead reading the below review article (from 2020). the 2014 article uses difficult to understand language.

Eric M. Pietras; Inflammation: a key regulator of hematopoietic stem cell fate in health and disease. Blood 2017; 130 (15): 1693–1698. doi: https://doi.org/10.1182/blood-2017-06-780882

https://ashpublications.org/blood/article/130/15/1693/36384/Inflammation-a-key-regulator-of-hematopoietic-stem

I found this by pasting your article's title into google scholar, hitting "cited by", sorting by date, and browsing until I found a review article.

The point of treating with G-CSF is that the stems cells divide, and can be recovered from the blood for stem cell treatments.

"expansion" . Here means an increase in the numbers of cells. But in plant biology it has the literal meaning of cells growing larger.

"phenotypic HSCs". Using the adjective phenotypic, the cells express the phenotype of HSCs. So the cells behave like HSCs

By itself, G-CSF makes the the HSCs divide for a while, then they stop dividing. That is, they become "quiescent".

This state of quiesence can then be interrupted. If the mice are treated with antibiotics to kill intestinal flora (or if mice are used that are germ-free), then the HSCs continue to divide.
The article calls this process of getting the HSCs to divide again "mitigating the G-CSF-mediated HSC repopulating defect"

Comment: So to paraphrase the in-quotes from the 2014 paper, G-CSF causes the expansion of bone marrow HSCs with the phenotype of low repopulating or self-renewal capacity? Since G-CSF causes BM niche HSCs to exit quiescence. I am assuming that the 2014 paper distinguishes BM niche HSCs from BM HSCs.

Comment: Perhaps say "eventual phenotype". The HSCs that divide after treatment with G-CSF, seem like normal HSC but eventually stop dividing and become insensitive to G-CSF.